# Clojure XPath xml processing

Tags: xml, xpath, clojure

I am using clojure's Xpath library for parsing data that comes from a api call. I need function msh-contents-try to generalize xml parsing, for any xml and any tags. The code looks like this:

```
(ns mashup-dsl.datamodel
 (:use [clj-xpath.core])

 (defn create-root-tag [tags] 
 (str "/"(apply str (interpose \/ tags))))

 (defn create-xpath [tag]
  (str "./" tag))    

(defn msh-contents-try [url mshpname root-tag tags]
  (let [events-xml (memoize (fn [] (slurp url)))
    xmldoc (memoize (fn [] (xml->doc (events-xml ))))
    items (take 5 ($x root-tag (xmldoc)))
    f (fn[item] (map #({(keyword %) ($x:text (create-xpath %) item)}) tags))]
    (zipmap tags [(vec (map f items)) mshpname])))
```

Function call looks like this

```
(msh-contents-try data-url "events" (create-root-tag ["search" "events" "event"]) [:title :url])
```

There was a mistake that was resolved with Eclipse restarting, now I get this strange result:

```
{:url "/search/events/event", :title []}
```

The result I was hoping for was something like this:

```
 {:title "events"
 :event-data [{ :title "event name 1"
              :url "url2"}
            {:title "event name 2"
             url "url 2"}]}
```

Comment: Sounds like you're using undeclared namespace prefixes. Where is the XPath that you're using?

Comment: @JLRishe I'm using Leiningen, so it's in Maven repository by default.

Comment: @JLRishe after I restarted Eclipse, the original problem was resolved, but now the problem is with the result of msh-contents-try function